# Querying and converting data using a lambda expression

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, lambda

Today I have a repository layer that access entity framework data and returns it to upper layers for usage. My basic code is as follows (SysLog is my model class, SYSLOG is the Entity Framework class that retrieves from database. They has some differences):

```
public List<SysLog> List()
{
    Entities dbContext = DAODbContext.Instance.EntitiesFactory();

    IQueryable<SYSLOG> query = dbContext.SYSLOG;

    ///
    /// Add the obrigatory wheres
    /// 
    query = query.Where(record => record.DELETED == "N");

    ///
    /// Add the select order 
    /// 
    query = query.OrderByDescending(record => record.DATETIME);

    ///
    /// Execute que query
    /// 
    List<SYSLOG> dbSysLogList = query.ToList();

    ///
    /// Copy the list to the final format
    /// 
    List<SysLog> returnList = new List<SysLog>();

    foreach (SYSLOG element in dbSysLogList)
        returnList.Add(NormalizedCopyFromDbObj(element));

    return returnList;
}
```

My problem is that I have a lot of these functions (ex: To List, To List based on date, To List based on type, wirh reverse sort order, with some attribute==something)...

I would like to change it to use LAMBDA EXPRESSIONS on input (to filter data) and in output (to send data to be queryable).

I had tried several combinations, but none of those seem to work. I need help to do it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try modifying this below to suit your needs.

```
public IQueryable<T> Query(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate) where T : class
{
    Entities dbContext = DAODbContext.Instance.EntitiesFactory();

    var dbSet = dbContext.Set<T>();

    return dbSet.Where(predicate);
}
```

This returns an `IQueryable` which you can call other LINQ extension methods on (`Count`, `ToList`, etc).

**UPDATE**
SysLog specific version (non-generic)

```
public IQueryable<SYSLOG> Query(Expression<Func<SYSLOG, bool>> predicate)
{
    Entities dbContext = DAODbContext.Instance.EntitiesFactory();

    var dbSet = dbContext.SYSLOG;

    return dbSet.Where(predicate);
}
```

Not sure why you are declaring your `dbContext` and instantiating it inside the method though. I've left it there to make it easier to read but you should consider changing that.

Comment: Thanks for that, but not sure I understood your point at the dbContext. dcContext gets an entity that is generated from EF. I have 2 EF models - onde for Oracle and onde for Database. So the factory will give me the EF Entity according to an internal parameter so that I can proceed with DB access...

Comment: @Mendez depending on your dev setup .. this would probably be difficult to test .. since the dbContext is tightly coupled to this method ... but i guess you can worry about all that later on :)

Comment: Yes. Furthermore, I´m thinking on how to call this new function. Sounds that I will need to pass <T> as my EF type, and that is not I need as I will not be decoupling EF and upper layer data...Thinking... Repair that SYSLOG (EF) is different than SysLog (common model on service layer).

Comment: @Mendez i opted to use generics so you could be free to use it with any entity (not just SysLog) but if you want me to modify it for just SysLog i could do that as well.

Comment: Yes, I understood generics. I just need to test it and see if I can pass a SysLog query to be done on a SYSLOG db object, even having same name properties in most fields.

Comment: @Mendez i've updated the answer though. added the non-generic version.

Comment: Thanks, but that made clear my point. Look at my code. At the end I have to translate data from SysLog to SYSLOG (I´m doing that in a foreach loop), as I need to return SysLog, not SYSLOG. So, the function must receive and send SysLog object, but internally work with EF SYSLOG object. I´m realizing I will not be able to do it like I´m thinking.... Using a SysLog lambda expression to get data from SYSLOG...

Comment: Just to add more info, SYSLOG can be Oracle or SQL Data depending on the model, that´s why I have my whole app working with SysLog normalized data... For example, Oracle does not have boolean type. The down layer and NormalizedCopy treats that for me...

Comment: @Mendez i'm not sure whats going on in this "NormalizedCopyFromDbObj" method so it's hard to say .. but you can do whatever projection you want .. you have an iquerable.

Comment: Yes, a query and them a new query. That´s what I tought. I will think how that will fit in my architecture... Thanks Scartag for the help.

Comment: This is bad to return an `IQueryable<>` on a context that you can't dispose of.

Answer (score 1):

Not entirely sure I understand what you're after, but if you're looking to create a single function that returns a list of entities based on some filtering criteria, I typically do the following.

First, I create a filtering object that contains all possible criteria I could filter on:

```
public class SysLogFilter
{
    public string Attribute1 {get;set;}
    public string Attribute2 {get;set;}
    public DateTime Date {get;set;}
}
```

Then, you pass this filter to your method and alter your query accordingly:

```
public List<SysLog> List(SysLogFilter filter)
{
    Entities dbContext = DAODbContext.Instance.EntitiesFactory();

    IQueryable<SYSLOG> query = dbContext.SYSLOG;

    if(!String.IsNullOrWhitespace(filter.Attribute1))
         query.Where(s => s.Attribute1 == filter.Attribute1);

    if(!String.IsNullOrWhitespace(filter.Attribute2))
         query.Where(s => s.Attribute2 == filter.Attribute2);

    if(filter.Date != null)
         query.Where(s => s.DATETIME == filter.Date)

    return query.ToList();
}
```

This is untested, hopefully it gives you something to work with.

Comment: I thought about this method, but I want a lambda expression on filter as I have complex attributes combinations.